# My code keeps giving me an error for a missing ; even though I have one

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse keeps telling me that I need a ';' before the '}' but I have one after the second print statement. Is there something I'm missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to CS1200");
    printf("\nMy name is Sam Proos");
}
```

Comment: Is it only eclipse telling you that, or does the error also appear during proper compilation?

Comment: Are you on OS X? If you are, then be careful with the double qoutes, because OS X replaces them with quotes that are prettier but are invalid characters for a c program.

Comment: Nope. Your code is fine (although you might add another `\n` after your name).

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I think the specific tag here that's causing this issue is [tag:eclipse].

Comment: @JL2210 It could be an eclipse-specific issue, but I haven't seen anything yet to confirm that hypothesis.  I've found that new members frequently tag the IDE they are working with whether or not it is actually related to the issue.  Were I to wager on the issue at hand, I'd place much higher odds on the issue being a failure to save before compiling than I would on an issue with the IDE.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse wants you to return a value from main. Is it the only error flagged, and does Eclipse recognize you are programming in C? Did you try the classic "Hello, world" program in your Eclipse, too?

Comment: There are no missing semicolons in the code you posted.  The code you posted compiles perfectly for me.  The error you're seeing must have to do with some discrepancy between what you've posted and what you're compiling; some factor that we can't see.